# How to stop the simulation when an error occurs in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

In Dymola, if an error occurs during the simulation, the calculation would be jammed. How could I stop the simulation now? I tried a lot of methods, but the only way that works right now is using the task manager to terminate the Dymola process.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to stop a stuck simulation in Dymola

1. The "Stop" button next to the "Simulation" button. The short-cut for this is F12
2. Create a empty file "stop" (with no extension) in Dymola's working directory.
3. Within the (Windows) command-window, hitting CTRL-C a different number of times

   - once: will give you a status of the progress of the integration
   - twice: will pause the simulation and will give you some online debugging possibilities
   - three times: stops the simulation (this will sometimes give you more of the result in the plots than using (1.)

Also you will find the sections "Diagnostics for stuck simulation" and "Debug facilities when running a simulation", which  corresponds to (3.), in the Dymola Manual (I think it was Volume 2).